# showing shared preference list into a list view in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I retrieve 5 data from the database(which has 2 column word and meaning) and save them into shared preference. So i have 5 items on shared preference. Now how can i show them into a listview. I tried many times but cant solve this.
My code is:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_of_wordmeanings = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.learn_getTestData();

    for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) 
    {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(i);

        String string = mCursor.getString(1);

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String word = mCursor.getString(0).toString();
            String meaning = mCursor.getString(1).toString();

             hm.put("key_word",word);
                hm.put("key_meaning",meaning);

             list_of_wordmeanings.add(hm);
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


    for (HashMap<String, String> map : list_of_wordmeanings)
         for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
         {
             editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
             editor.commit();

             String savedPref = sharedPreferences.getString(entry.getKey(), "");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),savedPref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
```

It toasts the 5 keys and values from the Toast.
Now i have to show these keys and respective values into a list view.
How can i do that??

Comment: What exactly is your question?  How to use a ListView?

Comment: I know how to use ListView but i can understand how to show the values of shared preference in a listView.@trevor-e

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
         {
             editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
             editor.commit();

             String savedPref = sharedPreferences.getString(entry.getKey(), "");
             result.add(savedPref);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),savedPref, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
```

And then pass this array list to your listview adapter...